# Spring boot resources properties from config dependency

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

So my project is dependent on some another one which is kinda shared config for several projects.
I have added it as dependency using maven. Now I can easly import classes from this depeneney project and use them.

So the question is how to copy some src/resources or test/resources files into my project or maybe I dont need to copy them but how to point to those files ? As I can import classess so this jar should be in classpath so how to point to resources?

```
classpath:shared_project_name.jar/src/resources/<file>
```

Maybe I should't use jar name?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing stuff between several projects i suggest you check out *Monorepos*.

Comment: I want to share only utils and some translations, switching to monorepo would be too time consuming